# Install go vouch-proxy on windows fails

Tags: windows, go

I want install the vouch-proxy on my windows 10 but it fails:

```
go get https://github.com/vouch/vouch-proxy
package https:/github.com/vouch/vouch-proxy: https:/github.com/vouch/vouch-proxy: invalid import path: malformed import path "https:/github.com/vouch/vouch-proxy": invalid char ':'
```

I am not familiar with GO, so I hope for help, thanks a lot

Comment: Hi. As a newcomer you should really read [about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) on the site. Nevertheless the answer to your problem is to remove the `https://` part, the package is named `github.com/vouch/vouch-proxy` and that's all go needs to install it.

Comment: @yorodm Oh no, what a shameful mistake. Thanks for your help. And thanks for the link, I read it, but can't see what's wrong with my question. What do you want to point out to me? I would like to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the https://

```
go get github.com/vouch/vouch-proxy
```